# Select a substring (date) and convert it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a table with a column DateFrom (Varchar) that uses format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

to get the time for a specific date I use this sql:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DateFrom FROM 12 FOR 5) AS From FROM calendar WHERE SUBSTRING(DateFrom FROM 1 FOR 10) = "'.$date.'"
```

this gives me:

```
HH:MM

.$date
```

(from datepicker) has format `DD.MM.YYYY`

I'm creating a website that should let the user see times associated with a date

can I convert the string from my database before checking if it's equal to `.$date`?

Or would it be better to change format from datepicker to `YYYY.MM.DD` instead?

Comment: Changing the format of the date picker is the easiest solution,  if users agree to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i finally solved it:

```
 $date1 = 18.02.2014;
 $date2 = 22.02.2014;

 $a = explode('.',$date1);
 $revdate1 = $a[2].'-'.$a[1].'-'.$a[0];
 $newdate1 = str_replace(".","-",$revdate1);

 $b = explode('.',$date2);
 $revdate2 = $b[2].'-'.$b[1].'-'.$b[0];
 $newdate2 = str_replace(".","-",$revdate2);


SELECT SUBSTRING(DateFrom FROM 1 FOR 10) AS Date, 
SUBSTRING(DateFrom FROM 12 FOR 5) AS StartTime, 
SUBSTRING(DateTo FROM 12 FOR 5) AS EndTime 
FROM Calendar WHERE SUBSTRING(DateFrom FROM 1 FOR 10) 
BETWEEN "'.$newdate1.'" AND "'.$newdate2.'"
```

I know DATETIME would be better but that was not an option here (not my database).
So this solution takes a date with format dd.mm.yyyy and reformats it to yyyy-mm-dd and checks it against the substring date from my table.

so the query prints all:
Date, StartTime, EndTime 
between two dates

Answer (score 1):

How about getting rid of the the substring stuff and using this instead?

```
 SELECT TIME(DateFrom) AS `From`
   FROM Calendar
  WHERE DATE(DateFrom) = STR_TO_DATE($date,'%d.%m.%Y')
```

This will work because your DateFrom field happens to be stored in the standard string format of a DATETIME object.

`From` is in backticks because it's a reserved word.

You really should consider changing the data type of your DateFrom column to DATETIME, and then indexing that column.  Then you can change your WHERE clause to this

```
  WHERE DateFrom >= STR_TO_DATE($date,'%d.%m.%Y')
    AND DateFrom <  STR_TO_DATE($date,'%d.%m.%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

and you will get a very great performance advantage.

Comment: I tried running this: 
SELECT TIME(DateFrom) AS From
   FROM Calendar
  WHERE DATE(DateFrom) = STR_TO_DATE('22.02.2014','%d.%m.%Y')
but i get #1064 when running this